# Convert Curl Request to Python Request

Tags: python

Here is the example curl request that I have trying to change to my python code:

```
 curl  'http://127.0.0.1:5985/_api/v2/ws/test2/upload_report' \
   -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
   --cookie "session=.eJw90M2KwjAQB_BXWXL2YGu9CB6UlGJhpgSCZeZS2FpNJ2YXqkI24rtv18O-wO__8VTdeRpuTm3u02NYqG48qc1TfXyqjWK9SyyUYVsWmMrUWDei9Etsj4FaDKydw-Qj5KZo9CWSNUu2uzXktQM5XSnxyJVZgTaRrYkk-xEt5ZQfVmT3DmcfKvrhcBQUKMgeIoQysb0knjMh-QIEliyQQzJZ0-IV_kx7DWDZY1WPmNCD9Fv1Wqj-Np27-7cfvv4noNTSVCZjXSaYK2KgiLqMTTtX1H7daMpmPnLFgtpHSk7YbN_c4zZM7ztUoV6_3rRiDA.DkoypQ.q7eGzh1oof8dKnbF4q6xD_n1d6o" \
   --form "file=@PATH/TO/FILE" \
   --form "csrf_token=IjYyYzhkNWQxMzA4MTZmMTQxMTliYTA5OTg2NWYzMWRmYzQ5MWM4Y2Ui.Dko4Zw.sZ-LLdGoxaNFUaySFFQMvyLecxc" \
   --compressed
```

I have the below python code to try to upload the file? However the API is returning a 400 error.

```
CSRF_TOKEN = get_csrf(session,token)
files = {"file": open(os.getcwd()+'/test.xml',"rb")}
data = {"csrf_token": CSRF_TOKEN, "file": os.getcwd() + "/test.xml"}
res = session.post(BASE_URI + '/_api/v2/ws/test2/upload_report', verify=False, files=files, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}, cookies={'session':token})
print res.text, res.status_code
pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the Content-Type header, a Multipart/form-data request must include a boundary value, and requests takes care of this for you, automatically, when you use `files`. By setting it manually, you actually ask `requests` not to handle this for you, and in doing so you broke the requirements.

Also, you do not need to set `file` twice. Set it just once, in the `files` structure:

```
CSRF_TOKEN = get_csrf(session,token)
files = {"file": open(os.getcwd()+'/test.xml',"rb")}
data = {"csrf_token": CSRF_TOKEN}
res = session.post(
    BASE_URI + '/_api/v2/ws/test2/upload_report', verify=False, 
    files=files, data=data,
    cookies={'session': token})
```

I'd also open the file object as a context manager so it'll be closed when the response is received:

```
CSRF_TOKEN = get_csrf(session,token)
data = {"csrf_token": CSRF_TOKEN}

with open('test.xml', "rb") as file_to_post:
    files = {"file": file_to_post}
    res = session.post(
        BASE_URI + '/_api/v2/ws/test2/upload_report', verify=False, 
        files=files, data=data,
        cookies={'session': token})
```

You do not need to use `os.getcwd()` at all, any relative path will be resolved against the current working directory anyway.